# Is is possible to create a template that automatically imports '#include' dependencies in Eclipse C++?

Tags: c++, eclipse, templates

using the Eclipse IDE 'Juno', you may use a template for Java that automatically imports all dependencies for a class such as:

```
${:import(org.apache.log4j.Logger)}
private static final Logger _logger = Logger.getLogger(${enclosing_type}.class);
```

I can't find an equivalent version of this for C++ using log4cpp. I believe that the ${enclosing_type} is equal to ${type_name} but can't find anything to include the libraries that may be dependent. A few blogs have mentioned that they use ctrl-space code insertion templates followed by ctrl-1 to fix dependencies, but ctrl-1 doesn't work for me to include missing libraries. In C++ is this possible using a namespace? I'm not terribly familiar with C++. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: With Java you can scan the compiled .class files to find the exported symbols. C++ doesn't work that way, so my guess is - probably not going to work.

Comment: @BoPersson Thanks. I was thinking that.

Comment: What's the reason you need this functionality?  Is it so you can switch logging on and off easily?  If so, you could use a conditional in a makefile to both link in the library and to set a precompile flag to turn on all the logging statements (and includes).

Comment: @john.pavan Thank-you.  This is the approach I'm going to take.